# Piping output of puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless

```
page.pdf({ path: "output.pdf", format: 'A4'});
```

expects a file to dump to.  Is there a way to redirect the output to a pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const content = await page.pdf({path: "output.pdf", format: 'A4'})
console.log(content.toString('hex'))
```

`content` will be a `Buffer` instance containing the pdf binary, then you can output

Comment: is there a way to do this without writing to any pdf?

Comment: @LastTribunal don't use the `path` option

Comment: I think I tied that, it complained that it expects a string or something.  Ill give it another shot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a recent thing, but you can do

```
await page.createPDFStream();
```

and that will return a Readable that you can pipe.